# HTTP parameter encoding

Tags: tomcat, encoding, parameters

Lately I have been working on creating a few HTTP services using a Tomcat 7.0 server. The code below is a html file that I used to test my service.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>              
                <form id="fm" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080
/DataService/ProductData?category=Ser + bø&location=Herlev##Vejle">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is regarding the category parameter "Ser + bø". On the server side it is read as 
"Ser   bø" with a three spaces instead of a space,"+",space. As far as I know the problem has likely to do something with encoding. I am using UTF-8 for the request. I have also change the configuration for the Tomcat server so that it uses UTF-8. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying your form action URL to pass parameters to back-end is not the right way of dealing with forms. The best way to avoid all of that is just to use a separate form parameters instead:

```
<form id="fm" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080
/DataService/ProductData?category=Ser %2B bø&location=Herlev##Vejle">
   <input type="hidden" name="category" value="Ser %2B bø">
   <input type="hidden" name="location" value="Herlev##Vejle">
   ...
</form>
```

That's because 
URL has it's own encoding rules, based on RFC 3986. Plus [stands for space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) there. So you should encode your URL prior to passing it to the server, either using JSP or JavaScript. Encoded `+` is `%2B`:

```
<form id="fm" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080
/DataService/ProductData?category=Ser %2B bø&location=Herlev##Vejle">
```

In case that it is a user input you will have to use JavaScript to encode it, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

The `+` is the URL encoded representation of a space. That's why you got it back as a space. You basically need to URL-encode the individual parameter names and values.

Given that you're running Tomcat, you're most likely also running JSP. In JSP, you can create properly encoded URLs with [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:url>` and `<c:param>` as follows:

```html
<c:url var="formActionURL" value="http://localhost:8080/DataService/ProductData">
    <c:param name="category" value="Ser + bø" />
    <c:param name="location" value="Herlev##Vejle" />
</c:url>
<form action="#{formActionURL}">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: he is doing POST - so why sending parameters in URL in the first place?